# HI! I'm new in react and trying to make multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, radio-button

I'm working to make multiple radio buttons that give me selected value when I select another radio button, the previous one automatically deselects.

It's also not showing the value of the selected radio button. I tried to use handleChange function on "onChange" event but got the error "handleChange undefined".

Here is my code...

```
    const InspectionsForm = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
  const fieldItems = [
    {
      name: "Front Bumper",
    },
    { name: "Roof" },
    { name: "Front Left Door" },
    { name: "Rear Left Door" },
    { name: "Front Right Door" },
    { name: "Rear Right Door" },
    { name: "Front Left Fender" },
    { name: "Rear Left Fender" },
    { name: "Front Right Fender" },
    { name: "Rear Right Fender" },
    { name: "Boot" },
    { name: "Rear Bumper" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="flex-row align-items-center inspection-section">
      <h3>CAR DETAILS</h3>
      <Container className="auction-filter box-shadow">
        <div className="container-buttons"></div>
      </Container>
      <div className="my-4">
        <h3>INSPECTIONS</h3>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Fields</th>
                <th>Original</th>
                <th>Repaint</th>
                <th>PR</th>
                <th>N/C</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {fieldItems.map((item)=>{
                return(
                  <tr>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Form.Check
                      className="radio-size"
                      type="radio"
                      aria-label="radio 1"
                      value="original"
                      name="field"
                      onChange={handleChange()}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <Form.Check
                      className="radio-size"
                      type="radio"
                      aria-label="radio 1"
                      value="repaint"
                      name="field"
                      onChange={handleChange()}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <Form.Check
                      className="radio-size"
                      type="radio"
                      aria-label="radio 1"
                      value="PR"
                      name="field"
                      onChange={handleChange()}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <Form.Check
                      className="radio-size"
                      type="radio"
                      aria-label="radio 1"
                      value="N/C"
                      name="field"
                      onChange={handleChange()}
                    />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                )
              })}

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div className="container-buttons">
          <Button className="mr-4" variant="light">
            Submit
          </Button>

          <Button variant="dark">Clear</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InspectionsForm;
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-brook-xw2b6?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine for me with `onChange={handleChange}`. Can you check this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-elbakyan-lvu7q?file=/src/App.js) and tell me what's acting strange for you?

*PS Remember to add `key={item.name}` when you create elements with map or iteration in general (key must be unique so I used item.name). And never use `class=''` but `className=''` in react elements.*

*PS2 I edited the code sandbox example to achieve what I thought you wanted to achieve. Basically it's convenient to generate the td mapping a options list. And then you have to add selected property to form.checkbox if state has the corrispondent property and its value is the option you're generating.*

Answer (score 1):

> when I select another radio button, the previous one automatically
> deselect

This is because you gave the same name attribute to the `Form.Check` component across the loop. You can avoid this by passing in an index or the name of the item itself.

> but got the error "handleChange undefined".

This comes because you called the function which return `void` inside onChange prop of `Form.Check`. Just pass the function as is without calling it inside `onChange`.

```
{fieldItems.map((item, index)=>{
  return(
    <tr>
    <td>{item.name}</td>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        className="radio-size"
        type="radio"
        aria-label="radio 1"
        value="original"
        name={`field${index}`}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </td>
  ...
}
```